# Bootstrap 3 Navbar Expands but will not Collapse

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to implement a responsive navbar in [Bootstrap 3](http://getbootstrap.com/components/) Things have been working for the most part. The bar even expands correctly. Then, when I press the responsive collapse button again the bar collapses about halfway and then drops back down.

This verifies that the Javascript is in place and that the CSS is in place correctly as well. I don't know how else this could be happening. Even in Plunkr it works, but not in my project. Any ideas?

```html
<div class="navbar">
   <div class="container">
      <button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" class="navbar-toggle collapsed">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Title</a>
      <div style="height: 0px;" class="nav-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse collapse">
         <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please prepare a jsFiddle or something like that you can help us help you better.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It turns out that I included a duplicate compiled Javascript and that there was some mixup with event listeners and so it was being buggy. Fixed.

Comment: same thing happened with me in BS 2.2... if this problem persists for other users, it's a good idea to double check your js

Comment: adding the step on how you did it, might help others on this

Answer (score 6):

I had the same exact issue and resolved it simply by shifting the `bootstrap.js` before any other `.js` I had at the bottom of the `<body>`.

Comment: ohh .. great.. your solution is worked for me. But sir , i didn't get why we have to do this..? means I placed `bootstrap.js` file at the bottom of the `<body>` , so what is reason of behind this..????