# bootstrap 3 navbar expands on small screens but remains stuck in the expanded state

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to implement the Bootstrap 3 navbar. Almost everything works but there is a bug. On small screens, the little menu icon appears. When I click it, the menu expands and it works. However, when I click the menu icon again, it refuses to collapse. The menu is then "stuck" in the permanently expanded state.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
            <img src="img/x_small.png" alt="X" style="padding:5px 15px;">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            </div> 
                <div id="navbar-collapse-1" class="navbar-collapse collapse" style="height:0px;">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#problem">Problem</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#synthesis">Synthesis</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#comments">Comments</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#solution">Solution</a></li>
                    <li><a href="research.php">Research</a></li>
                    <li><a href="press.php">Press Info</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="navbar-text navbar-right hidden-xs hidden-sm" style="color:#CCC">X: text here &nbsp;</p>
                </div>
          </div>
</div>
```

I know that other people have had issues with the navbar ([Bootstrap 3 Navbar Expands but will not Collapse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18022788/bootstrap-3-navbar-expands-but-will-not-collapse)) but the problem appears to be different - in the other question, the menu collapses partially then re-opens. Mine does not even respond to the button in any way, hence I'm filing a separate question.

====== EDIT & ANSWER =========

The solution was simple albeit non-intuitive: I reversed the order in which my javascript files were called. Instead of the default order:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I used:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

and somehow everything worked. I don't know why though. Sharing this solution in case others stumble upon it.

Comment: I know this is kind of old, but the appropiate reaction to yourself finding the solution is answering to your question, and then accept it a day later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple albeit non-intuitive: I reversed the order in which my javascript files were called. Instead of the default order:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

I used:

```
<link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
```

and somehow everything worked. I don't know why though. Sharing this solution in case others stumble upon it.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same symptom: the toggle button in tha navbar remained active and the navbar menu remained open. The closing animation played when clicking the button (bootstrap added the "closing" class to the menu) but then right after the closing animation was finished, the "in" class was added back to the menu which keeps it in its open state.

I tried the answer of GK79 and it solved this problem but create other problems - for example, the bootstrap scrollspy plugin stopped working if I loaded bootstrap before jQuery.

For me the cause was that jQuery and Bootstrap were loaded at the end of the HTML body rather than in the header.

Moving the script tags from the HTML footer to the header and then loading jQuery first and bootstrap 3 after that inside of the HTML header solved the problem for me.